# Poorly Downscaled Jpeg Image using C#

Tags: c#, image

I'm trying to downscale a jpeg image from 3028x4051 to 854x1171. This results in an image which is close to 1M pixels and maintains the aspect ratio. The original image is [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/RAFAEL_-_Madonna_Sixtina_%28Gem%C3%A4ldegalerie_Alter_Meister%2C_Dresde%2C_1513-14._%C3%93leo_sobre_lienzo%2C_265_x_196_cm%29.jpg/656px-RAFAEL_-_Madonna_Sixtina_%28Gem%C3%A4ldegalerie_Alter_Meister%2C_Dresde%2C_1513-14._%C3%93leo_sobre_lienzo%2C_265_x_196_cm%29.jpg). The image scales down very poorly though. Below is a section of the image. The top is the image scaled down in MS paint, the bottom it is scaled down programatically in C#. I've included the code I've used to downscale and save it. Anyone know what could be going on?

[image]

```
using (IRandomAccessStream sourceStream = await sourceFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    BitmapDecoder myDecoder = await GetDecoder(sourceStream);
    BitmapTransform myTransform = new BitmapTransform() { ScaledHeight = h, ScaledWidth = w };
    await myDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
            myTransform,
            ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
            ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
    BitmapEncoder myEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, destinationStream);
            myEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, w, h, 96, 96, pixelData.DetachPixelData());
    await myEncoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: Check [Bitmap Interpolation Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapinterpolationmode)

Comment: I tried using `WriteableBitmap myWriteableBitmap = img1.Resize(w, h height, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);` The image still comes out quite poorly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you create a new instance of `BitmapTransform`, you can specify the interpolation mode. Linear is the default mode, so to get a better result you need to try with Cubic or Fant.

```
using (IRandomAccessStream sourceStream = await sourceFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    BitmapDecoder myDecoder = await GetDecoder(sourceStream);
    BitmapTransform myTransform = new BitmapTransform() { ScaledHeight = h, ScaledWidth = w, InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant };
    await myDecoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
            myTransform,
            ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation,
            ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage);
    BitmapEncoder myEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, destinationStream);
            myEncoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, w, h, 96, 96, pixelData.DetachPixelData());
    await myEncoder.FlushAsync();
}
```